# How to install 'glogg' on a Mac?

Tags: command-line, mac

I just tried to install [Glogg](http://glogg.bonnefon.org/download.html) on a Mac, which kind of worked, but this tool does not seem to be available on the command line. When I try to start it on the comment line it says:

```
mypc:Space me$ glogg
-bash: glogg: command not found
```

So what to do? Do I miss something? Is there some special and stupid Mac-thing to be done, so I can use the application on the command line?

It shows up in 'Application' in the Finder-thingy, though....

Answer (score 3):

glogg is not a command-line app in macOS, but a GUI one.  Assuming you installed in /Applications, which appears to be where the developer suggests it should be, you can launch it via the following command:

```
mypc:Space me$ /Applications/glogg.app/Contents/MacOS/glogg
```

If you insist on launching it from the command-line, you could create an alias in your `.bashrc`, like so:

```
alias glogg='/Applications/glogg.app/Contents/MacOS/glogg'
```

Answer (score 1):

While setting an shell alias—[as MMB’s answer suggests](https://superuser.com/a/1249814/167207)—should work, the downside is that alias is restricted to only the user that has that alias set.

A better method that can easily allow any user to access `glogg` is is to set a symbolic link from the command line binary in the app to the `/usr/local/bin/` directory like this:

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/glogg.app/Contents/MacOS/glogg /usr/local/bin/glogg
```

`/usr/local/bin/` is where locally installed binaries typically reside so this would make the install more “normal” that having to deal with a full path buried in an alias when scripting and such.

Answer (score 1):

[MMB](https://superuser.com/a/1249814/167207) and [Giacomo1968](https://superuser.com/a/1249819/167207)’s answers are great, but I’ll throw a third one in here because I find it convenient:

```
open -a glogg
```

When you pass an app name, even miscapitalized, to `open -a`, it will be smart enough to look at the names of all your apps (minus the `.app`, if you left it off), and find one that matches. You do have to specify the full name up to the `.app`, including spaces, if any, which would have to be escaped. So for example you can do `open -a google\ chrome` to launch `/Applications/Google Chrome.app`.

Note that this generally knows about ALL the apps you have access to, not just the ones in `/Applications` and `/Applications/Utilities`. So if you have apps in your home directory or somewhere else, it'll find those too.